# Russian army refuses to demobilize a conscript on demobilization day?

Tags: military, russia

Suppose someone joined the Russian army as a conscript in Rostov-on-Don.  But on their demobilization day, they are told they will not be demobilized and instead will be held "until further notice" ("до особого распоряжения"). Is there a legal basis for this action, and are there legal avenues to appeal it?

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question in such a way that it is no longer a solicitation for specific legal advice, as that is against the rules for posting questions.  Hopefully I have achieved that while retaining the general case and direction of interest of the question.  The OP may of course undo or re-edit if they feel the edit has failed at such things.

Comment: Thank you, looks good, I didn't realize it's again the rules.

Comment: With the situation evolving in Russia as of today... I strongly doubt that the courts would look at the case for months or at all, even if there can be a case.

Comment: I'm afraid most countries in most wars have not let soldiers go during an active campaign just because their "time was up". Whether they pass a law that makes it legal or are a dictatorship where that doesn't matter, one way or the other that is the norm. I would be very surprised if todays Russia would be the glowing exception of humanity in this group.

Answer (score 2):

As many Western analysts see it, Russia does not have the **rule of law**, it is an autocracy which makes use of the legal system to enforce the will of the central government. That is, in any important lawsuit the outcome is not determined by judges looking at the law, it is determined by power plays in the Kremlin. And the case you describe would certainly be important for the precedent it sets.

Russian analysts might disagree, of course.